# Why is swagger ignoring my authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openid-connect

I am trying to secure a swagger interface withj OpenId Connect.

I can login using OIDC and swagger shows me as authorised:

[image]
but when I do 'try it out' the authentication is ignored and a login box pops up:

[image: ![enter image description here]

In my class which `extends SpringBootServletInitializer` I have:

```java
   @Bean
   @ConditionalOnProperty("security.oauth2.client.clientId") 
    public SecurityScheme securityScheme(Environment environment, OAuth2ClientProperties clientProperties) {
        String authorizationUri = environment.getRequiredProperty("security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri");
        String accessTokenUri = environment.getRequiredProperty("security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri");

        LoginEndpoint loginEndpoint = new LoginEndpoint(authorizationUri);
        TokenRequestEndpoint tokenRequestEndpoint =
                new TokenRequestEndpoint(authorizationUri, clientProperties.getClientId(), clientProperties.getClientSecret());
        TokenEndpoint tokenEndpoint = new TokenEndpoint(accessTokenUri, "auth_code");
        GrantType grantType = new AuthorizationCodeGrant(tokenRequestEndpoint, tokenEndpoint);
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope(authorizationScopeGlobal, authorizationScopeGlobal);
        return new OAuthBuilder()
                .name(securitySchemaOAuth2)
                .grantTypes(Arrays.asList(grantType))
                .scopes(Arrays.asList(authorizationScope))
                .build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope(authorizationScopeGlobal, authorizationScopeGlobalDesc);
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference(securitySchemaOAuth2, authorizationScopes));
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityConfiguration security(OAuth2ClientProperties clientProperties) {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(
                clientProperties.getClientId(),
                clientProperties.getClientSecret(),
                securitySchemaOAuth2,
                "test-app",
                "apiKey",
                ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, 
                "api_key",
                " " /*scope separator*/);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/v1/.*")).build();
    }
```

and a class with:

```java
 @ApiModel(value = "Template", description = "Template of REST APIs")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class TemplateServiceImplementation {

...

@ApiOperation(httpMethod = "GET", value = "Call Get method",
        notes = "See Get method")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/calltemplate/{param}/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Structure> callGet(@PathVariable("param") String param, HttpServletRequest hreq) {

    MultiValueMap<String, String> mapParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    mapParams.add("param", param);
    Structure structure = restTemplate.getForObject(callGetEndpoint, Structure.class, mapParams);

    ResponseEntity<Structure> thisresponse = new ResponseEntity<Structure>(structure, HttpStatus.OK);
    return thisresponse;
}
```

Sorry for all the code. So how do I make the GET use my OIDC authentication?

When I cancel the login, curl is:
`curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJraWQiOiJyc2ExIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMy lots more encrypted text' 'http://localhost:8080/v1/calltemplate/%7B%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%20%20%22path%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%20%20%22version%22%3A%20%22string%22%20%7D/'`
request url:
`http://localhost:8080/v1/calltemplate/%7B%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%20%20%22path%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%20%20%22version%22%3A%20%22string%22%20%7D/`

and other response variables:

[image]

EDIT Forgot to metion my `WebSecurityConfig`:

```java
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", 
            "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html"
            , "/webjars/**", "/csrf", "/");
}
```

UPDATE
Output of network:
[image]

Comment: Do you have `user-authorization-uri` properly defined? The screenshots show well whats going on in the UI, but in order to debug it you'll better provide what the Browser tools display, especially in the network tab.

Comment: Thanks. I will put this up this evening (in about 4 or 5 hours).

Comment: What sort of things do you need to see in network tab? I have added what I can see.

Comment: Wrt `user-authorization-uri` this is set in my application.properties.

Comment: Details of the third line [here](https://ufile.io/22v3s).

Comment: The network tab shows the swagger js trying to access some resource and getting 403 (forbidden). If you click on it you can ser the headers being sent, the full url being requested and so on. This is the way to go

Comment: Thanks. They are in my comment 'Details of the third line...'.

Comment: what kind of url is that? it looks very wrong `http://localhost:8080/v1/calltemplate/%7B%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%20%20%22path%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%20%20%22version%22%3A%20%22string%22%20%7D/`